# Use Raspberry with two devices that require 3.3v pin

Tags: gpio, pi-2, hardware, electronics, voltage

I'm planning a project with an RFID reader that connects to the GPIO pins on a RPi2 and will use the 3.3v pin. Additionally I wanted to add an active buzzer, which also would require an 3.3v pin.

Is it possible to share the 3.3v pin or do I have to add resistors in order to use the 5v pin somehow?

Active Buzzer: https://arduinomodules.info/ky-012-active-buzzer-module/

RFID Reader: [https://www.amazon.com/SunFounder-Mifare-Reader-Arduino-Raspberry/dp/B07KGBJ9VG](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07KGBJ9VG)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can connect as many wires as you want to a 3V3 pin (pins 1 and 17).

Similarly you can connect as many wires as you want to a 5V pin (pins 2 and 4).

Similarly you can connect as many wires as you want to a ground pin.

Comment: Would it be appropriate to address the fact that the 3V3 pin will source only a limited amount of current?